# PostgreSQL cursor with arguments

Tags: postgresql, cursor, arguments, postgresql-9.1

As the documentation describes [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-cursors.html), I need to declare a cursor that accepts arguments at OPEN time.

My query looks something similar to:

> DECLARE cur CURSOR (argName character varying) FOR SELECT * FROM "TableName" WHERE "SomeColumn" = argName;

When I do this, I get a lovely error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: DECLARE cur CURSOR (argName character varying) FOR SELECT * FROM...
                           ^
```

It seems that PostgreSQL is not accepting this form of cursor declaration.
Is there any way to solve this? Any workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
DECLARE 
  argName varchar;
  cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM "TableName" WHERE "SomeColumn" = argName;
```

The `argName` will be taken into the query when you `OPEN` this cursor.

Comment: Thanks! That looks promising.

Comment: Question:
I should CLOSE and OPEN _cur_ after changing argName to a new value, right?

Comment: @gcontreras Yes. When cursor is opened it does not changes its query and params.

Answer (score 4):

That syntax is only valid inside plpgsql functions.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted, but I changed it to Igor's because yours just states my mistake, while his actually offers a workaround, which was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html

```
DECLARE
    key integer;
    curs4 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM tenk1 WHERE unique1 = key;
BEGIN
    key := 42;
    OPEN curs4;
```

From: